# How can I embed a webpage in a MS Word Doc

Tags: microsoft-word

All,
 Is there any way of embedding a webpage in a MS Word 2007 document, similar to having an iFrame object in the Word doc, with any changes to the underlying webpage being updated as appropriate?

Many thanks for any help on this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [the best info](http://forum.soft32.com/mac/Embedding-web-page-document-ftopict89638.html) I was able to find, which states that you can either write a VBA macro:

```
Sub Macro1() 
Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, 
Text:="INCLUDETEXT ""HardDriveName:FileName.htm""", PreserveFormatting:=True 
End Sub
```

or (in Word 2007), go to Insert->Quick Parts->Field... then under "Field Names" choose "Include Text", state the URL, and press OK.  This does not look very good, however, since I believe that Word is not really built for embedding web pages.

Comment: Thanks- I feared this was the case. Arguably word isnt 'built for' such purposes so I guess this makes sense- c'est la vie!

Answer (score 3):

You can go to Insert >> Object >> Text from File >> select the file (in html format) >> Insert (at the bottom right corner) >> Insert as link.  This will allow you to update information in Word by simply pressing F9 when something on the page was changed and saved again in html format.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach is to simply copy the file and paste it into the Word document. Double click on the file, a pop up will appear asking you for the confirmation of opening the Html file. I tried it out with Ms- Word 2013. I had a requirement of showing a distribution of oil wells that we plotted on the maps.

Answer (score 1):

Try:
Insert >> Quick Parts >> Field >> Choose "IncludePicture"  add the URL and then click "Do not store data with document".

This should force the document to get the data from the internet.

Works with Pictures, didn't try whole web pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to `Insert -> Online video` and then paste an `iframe` under embedded code for online video.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are Insert->Object->Text from file will be what you need if you space your document just right before.